# Can a Windows network issue remain undetected by the ping command?

Tags: networking, ping

Is it technically possible that a problem with a Windows Network does not manifest itself as packet drops when the ping command is used?

If yes,
What are some other ways to detect it?

**Reason I ask:**
We have suspected network issues in our web application hosted over a windows intranet from time to time, but each time, have been unable to follow up with the network team as the ping stat between the computers showed 0% packet loss and no latency.

Comment: Ping only checks if a device can respond to pings. To be clear, you suspect packets are dropping but want to know if it should also be manifesting itself as dropped ICMP packets? And you IT staff will not help unless it does?

Comment: @bokken74 Opened a _detailed question_ with my actual problem at ServerFault:
[<ServerFault Q>](http://serverfault.com/questions/785005/probable-network-issue-despite-healthy-ping-stat)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there can be further issues with the networking that ping would not be able to detect.  Ping is just a tool that normally tells the user "Yes this device can communicate with the other device and it takes this long to do it." or "The other device did not respond to my requests in the amount of time that was allotted."  Ping isn't really designed for much more than that.

> Reason I ask: We have suspected network issues in our web application hosted over a windows intranet from time to time, but each time, have been unable to follow up with the network team as the ping stat between the computers showed 0% packet loss and no latency.

If you can occasionally communicate with the server the way that you want to, then your IT team will probably tell you that there's nothing they can do, because they can't.  The reason for this is that it's more than likely an issue with the web application that is running on there that's having an issue.  You could probably ask them to check for performance issues with the server that the app is running on to see if that's the cause of your problem.  If that doesn't work, then your web app is having issues.

If your web app is HTTP based, then you can try to use Fiddler to see if it can help you track down what's wrong.  You can find it on [their website](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/web-app-performance-testing).  It's free too.  If Fiddler doesn't work for you, then the next tool that might be able to help is called Wireshark.  It's an advanced program though, so you may need someone else to help you use it.

Comment: I believe the problem is not with a webapp, but the windows network itself/something else.
I posted another Q at ServerFault with details (The question here at SuperUser was more of a theoretical one):
[Probable Network Issue Despite Healthy Ping Stat](http://serverfault.com/questions/785005/probable-network-issue-despite-healthy-ping-stat)

Comment: Then the first part of my answer still stands.  Yes, there can be issues with the network that ping cannot find.  I'll give you an answer in a bit on the other site.